# Using terminal shortcuts with a non-root user

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, root

I have added a non-root user to my Linux os to use it for my daily needs. However, I am not able to use shortcuts I am used to.

To use my previous codes I normally press ***UP*** or ***DOWN*** button on my keyboard. Now with a non-root user, it shows

```
$ ^[[A  // When I press UP arrow
$ ^[[B   // or DOWN arrow and so on...
```

> Why a nonroot user cannot use shortcuts and how can I use them

Comment: Just run /bin/bash and enjoy. You may need to create / copy bash profile for full experience.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you write a detailed answer when you have time? I'd like to now why should I run /bin/bash

Comment: Can downvoters please comment to make the question better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks your default shell is not bash.
You can check it by running (when not root)

```
echo $SHELL
```

or

```
ps -p `echo $$`
```

My best guess it is ksh.

You don't have to use bash - but is used by most people as it is most user friendly and should be available for all distros.

There are other shells - ksh, csh, tcsh, zsh or fish.
Last two are nice alternative to bash.